# Почему не всплывает alert при нажатии пробела?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Почему мы не видим всплывающее окно (результат работы функции `alert` в Chrome) при нажатии пробела, в отличие от нажатия на другие клавиши, которые давали нам всплывающее окно?

Answer (score 1):

В Chrome, как и в других браузерах, эти клавиши закрывают всплывающее окно:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- (пробела)

Comment: Но всё же: если `Enter` или `Esc` зажаты, то окно появляется и сразу исчезает. В случае пробела окно закрывается только при отпускании пробела. Браузер Opera 30.0.